# Rails has_many, how to achieve nested association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, has-many-through, has-many

I'm trying to implement nested has_many through association. I need to establish association between Team and Match through Umpire. I fail to do it using rails 5 has_many through association.

Here is my models:

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :umpires
  has_many :matches, through: :umpires
end

class Umpire < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :team
  has_many :matches, -> (umpire){ unscope(where: :umpire_id).where('matches.first_umpire_id =  :umpire_id OR matches.second_umpire_id = :umpire_id', umpire_id: umpire.id,)}
end

class Match < ApplicationRecord
  # first_umpire_id (integer)
  # second_umpire_id (integer)
end
```

For me `Umpire.first.matches` works but when I try `Team.first.matches` I get following error:

`` ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'matches.umpire_id' in 'on clause': SELECT `matches`.* FROM `matches` INNER JOIN `umpires` ON `matches`.`umpire_id` = `umpires`.`id` WHERE `umpires`.`team_id` = 1 AND (matches.first_umpire_id =  1 OR matches.second_umpire_id = 1) ``

Answer (score 0):

The `Umpire` model should have two `belongs_to` relationships, one for the `Team` model and one for the `Match` model. Also, the `Match` model should have a `has_many through` association as well, if you want to make it acessible in both directions.

The code should look like this:

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :umpires
  has_many :matches, through: :umpires
end

class Umpire < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :team
  belongs_to :match
end

class Match < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :umpires
  has_many :teams, through: :umpires
end
```

This example should work if you have your migrations set up properly.

Comment: A match have two umpires, `first_umpire_id`, `second_umpire_id`. Umpire can be associated with match as a first umpire or second umpire. Not sure if this fix works.